# Is it possible to provide Speech Recognition input to a website from the iPad?

Tags: speech-recognition, ipad-2, ipad-mini

Is there a way for a website to have an ipad (2 or higher) provide input via speech?

I.e., they speak into the ipad mic and the website receives the text.